# Installing Ubuntu Server 20.04 on Intel Nuc 10

Tags: server, 20.04, intel-nuc

I am considering upgrading my home server from NUC8i3 to NUC10i5. There are some old complaints on the web regarding LAN drivers. Was it fixed already? Can someone confirm painless installation of Ubuntu Server 20.04 on NUC 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a chance and worked without any problems. Smooth and easy installation of Ubuntu Server 20.04 on NUC10i5FNK. No LAN or 4k display issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have a BXNUC10i7FNH1.  Both Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Clear Linux installed but ethernet does not work.  I also tried using an ethernet-to-USB adapter with Ubuntu Server, but that didn't work either.  I installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, and both wifi and the ethernet-usb adapter work, but the onboard ethernet doesn't work.  My plan is to roll with desktop as a server until there's a good driver for the ethernet NIC.